# The Page Footer contains table in Prawn PDF

Tags: ruby-on-rails, footer, prawn

I've been combating this footer problem in Prawn PDF since last year. My page footer contains a table. Normally, table rows will flow on to the next page. My problem is how can I prevent the footer from appearing from previous page? I want it to appear only in the last page and intact.

Can someone share how did you find a solution about this?

below is the screenshot. The footer part is Total accounted value up to On hand count figure.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I don't have your code I will post an example I've used:

```
    footer_table = pdf.make_table(data) do
      cells.borders = []
    end
    pdf.start_new_page if (pdf.cursor - footer_table.height).negative?
    footer_table.draw
```

So in the last line you will check the whole table fits on the the current page, if not it will create a new page.

Comment: This answer will justify my solution. However, I forgot to get back here. I was able to come up with the same approach. Thank you so much @paulo for posting your answer.